# Error: 'firefox' not found when running Selenium web scraping code in Docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have been trying to do web scraping from my web application that has been dockerized.

We are doing web scrapping using selenium web driver to get data from webpages.
Below is the code used for the same :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import geckodriver_autoinstaller
id = https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps&hl=en_IN&gl=US
def appopen(id):
        print("start driver " )
        geckodriver_autoinstaller.install() 
        PROXY = "10.68.248.34:80" 
        webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
           "httpProxy": PROXY,
           "sslProxy": PROXY,  
           "proxyType": "MANUAL",
           }
       opts = FirefoxOptions()
       opts.add_argument("--headless")
       driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), options=opts)
       driver.get(id)
       print("inside driver " )
```

But when i run the code , getting attached error while trying to hit the driver .

`[Error 2]: no such file or directory :'firefox'`

I have tried having the `firefox.exe` file and also gecko driver files inside the container so that it recognize it , but still getting the error.

Am expecting it to run the driver and open the URL on browser and do web scrapping as it does in windows machine without being dockerized.